# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Server configuration procedure - defining the .war file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

What is the war file that i should define in the "worklight server configuration description?"

After installing all components from installation manager go to:
Windows Start Menu -> IBM Worklight Server 6.1 -> Server Configuration Tool

In the new window that pops up go to Create a new WL server configuration. Enter a name and the next screen of this wizard ask for a worklight project war.

Is it a projects war file or something in the server installation folder?

Comment: What is "worklight server configuration description"? Where do you see it? Explain your scenario, provide background information...

Comment: i edited and added the steps to find it. This only applies to worklight server version 6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this section in the Configuration tool refers to the .war file of the Worklight project you have created using Worklight Studio.

In your Worklight project look inside the `bin` folder.
There you will find a .war file.

You can review the following training module to getting a better overview:

- [Moving from development environment to stand-alone QA and production servers](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/10_01_Moving_from_development_environment_to_stand-alone_QA_and_production_servers.pdf)

Also read through this Information Center topic:

- [Deploying the project WAR file](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_deploy_wl_project.html)